# Youtube API comments order is incorrect/ Webpage doesn't load youtube Correctly

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

So there are two issues as I tried to solve a problem. Solving either of them will be fine for me

Issue 1:
I have been trying to get a program to show me the "order" of a certain comment. However I ran into an issue while implementing the API.

First of all I got the HTTP request from here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list

My HTTP was:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&textFormat=plainText&part=id&videoId=26P7y8gEkiQ&maxResults=100&order=relavence

Now this will get me a list which has comments and their IDs. All fine except for one problem.

The order that appears in that page is not the same one you see on Youtube! Which is confusing since the relavence should cover that. But for some reason... it doesn't!

Any Clue what is going wrong here?

Edit: I have been trying to get the order of comments using C#/Vb.net. Problem was that getting the page directly (Youtube) didn't load the comments. now i used YT API but its not doing what it should have.

2nd Issue: I tried to load youtube Webpage using both HTTPRequest and a Webbrowser. Both do not load the comments for some reason. I used this approach to try and scrape the comments directly from the HTML document. The comments seem to be "loading" indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, comments in YouTube is sorted by "Top comments" or "Newest first". By using the [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#parameters), you can get only comments ordered by `time` (Comment threads are ordered by time. This is the default behavior.) or `relevance` (Comment threads are ordered by relevance.). Here's a related thread which might help: [Get comments thread for a YouTube video using api v3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887427/get-comments-thread-for-a-youtube-video-using-api-v3-0)

Comment: I get that, But is there any way to get the "Top Comments" order from the API? Relevance seems to be difference.